# Search and Display Records from Different Tables using one search box

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have 4 SQL Tables with similar data fields. The reason for their separation is because they contain data from different locations. I have implemented a search box that is able to pull and display the records from these tables. However, there is a fourth table with totally different fields I have tried implementing the same on it but with no luck.

I tried creating a table within the same if function but inside a different @foreach given that they reside in the same model class

```
public class MemberViewModel
{
    public string Client { get; set; }
    public string PolicyNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> PolicyType { get; set; }
    public string InsurerName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> RenewalDate { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
}

public class DisplayData
{
    public List<MemberViewModel> Search(List<string> keywords)
    {
        StringBuilder sqlbuilder = new StringBuilder();

        sqlbuilder.Append("  select * from SingleView  where");

        foreach (string item in keywords)
        {
            sqlbuilder.AppendFormat("([Telephone] like '%{0}%' or     [Client] like '%{0}%' or [PolicyNo] like '%{0}%' or [PolicyType] like '%{0}%') and ", item);
        }
        string sql = sqlbuilder.ToString(0, sqlbuilder.Length - 5);

        return QueryList(sql);
    }
```

This is the View

```
@if (ViewBag.Message == true)
    {
        <label id="lblMessage" style="color: #6fcdcd;">Enter Phone Number</label>
    }
    else
    {
        if (Model != null)

        {

            if (Model.Count() != 0)

            {
                <div class="container">
                    <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Client</th>
                                <th>Policy No</th>
                                <th>Policy Type</th>
                                <th>Insurer Name</th>
                                <th>Renewal Date</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Telephone</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        @foreach (var item in Model.OrderByDescending(m => m.Client))
                        {

                            if (item.Status == "CURRENT")
                            {
                                @:
                                <tr style="background-color:#13994a  ;text-align:center;font-family:Calibri">
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Client)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.PolicyNo)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.PolicyType)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.InsurerName)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.RenewalDate)
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Status)
                                    </td>
```

Comment: first you said all 4 tables have same fields, and in last point you are saying that 4th table with totally different fields. make it clear first, what you expect please mention.

Comment: sorry I meant I have 4 tables, three have same fields

Comment: You can create one `SQL VIEW` and call in `store procedure` with  `search parameter` for specific you perform operation such as `AND` `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use some list with object type and then use it for every table as you want for example:

```
List<object> l = new List<object>();
        l.Add("sssss");
        l.Add(1);
        l.Add(new SomeObject()
        {
            Id = 1,
            LastNane = 23,
            Name = 1,
            RegDate = DateTime.Now
        });
```